# Converting an IMA file to an IMG file

Tags: virtualbox, windows-3.1, img

In a moment of extreme geekism, I've decided to install Windows 3.11 in Virtual Box. However, VirtualBox only accepts IMG files for floppy disks, and I've only been able to download IMA images of installation disks.

Does someone knows a IMA to IMG converter (no "google it" answers, it's been done, and I've not found what I was searching for) ? I've tried to simply rename the files, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this sometimes with an excellent tool called [WinImage](http://www.winimage.com/). Unluckily, it's shareware, but there are no limitations other than time limit.

Comment: I downladed WinImage, but I don't seem to find how to convert the ima file to img..could you help me ?

(i know, searching a little more in the menus could help, but if you have the info, it'd help me)

Comment: Basically .ima files are same with .img, but because renaming didn't solved the problem I remembered that when similar situation happened with me I opened files with WinImage and re-saved as .ima again: they were really compressed with some ZIP modification and wrongly named as .ima (compressed images must be callen .img).
Sorry for delay...

Answer (score 1):

VirtualBox now supports .IMA files and lets you boot from it. Just update it to the latest version and it should let you load the files that you have.